# How to exclude the file type in find , exec and grep?

Tags: grep, find

I am trying to find out the file in which the following flag is used - 
TRACE_WANTED". However, I don't want the find to search this flag in .c and .h. How can I issue a command to exclude the find from *.c and *.h files.

Here is the typical command I am using -

```
find ./ -iname  *.c -exec grep -iHrn  TRACE_WANTED {} \;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GNU `grep` has the ability to exclude globs from its recursive searches built in.  Try:

```
grep -iHrn  --exclude='*.c' --exclude='*.h' TRACE_WANTED
```

This searches recursively starting from the current directory, just like your `find` command.  It excludes all `*.c` and `*.h` files.

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to find the files which contains the word TRACE_WANTED, excluding *.c and *.h files, you don't even need to use *find*, grep alone can do this work for you:

```
 grep -r --exclude={"*.c","*.h"} TRACE_WANTED ./
```

The quotes are unnecessary in bash, but necessary in zsh by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . ! -name '*.[ch]' -type f -exec grep -l TRACE_WANTED {} +
```

Or if you can use a `grep` with `-r`ecursive search:

```
grep -lr --exclude='*.[ch]' TRACE_WANTED
```